# Android firebase realtime database

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase

я пытаюсь отправить в firebase database пост с картинкой и данными, но почемуто загружается только картинка, а класс mDatabaseUsers.addValue... не выполняется, почему и как исправить.

```
button_newPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final String postTitle = "PostTitle";
            final String postDescription = "PostDescription";
            StorageReference filepath = storage.child("post_image").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    final Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Uploaded Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    final DatabaseReference newPost = databaseReference.push();
                    mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            newPost.child("title").setValue(postTitle);
                            newPost.child("description").setValue(postDescription);
                            newPost.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                            newPost.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                            newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isComplete()) {
                                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: что значит "не выполняется"? Как я правильно понимаю вы сетите новые данные, а в onDataChange ждете коллбек с обновленными данными и он не отрабатывает?

Comment: Да, при нажатии на кнопки не выполняется класс onDataChange, а выполняется onCancelled

Answer (score 0):

То что сразу бросается в глаза у Вас слушатель инициализируется после того как происходит успешная операция. т.е. даже при успехе Вы пропустите ивент, а так же будете подписываться каждый раз при отрабатывании onSuccess(). Короче выносите намного выше в иерархии, например в OnCreate() - вот этот кусок кода:

```
mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        newPost.child("title").setValue(postTitle);
                        newPost.child("description").setValue(postDescription);
                        newPost.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                        newPost.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                        newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isComplete()) {
                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Проверяйте снова и если будет отрабатывать onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) - вытащите из databaseError - текст ошибки

Comment: я взял этот код отсюда, проблема находится в PostActivity
https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/build-a-simple-blog-app-with-firebase-in-android-studio-b6482275408